# How to optimize the quadratic sieve setup arguments?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, sieve-theory

What would be the best strategy optimizing the quadratic sieve setup?

Below is the list of the configurations used by [my quadratic sieve algorithm](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/quadratic-sieve-Java), I would like to build a program that will run several tests to find the optimal setup, but the problem is that there is a non-trivial dependency between the params and I simply don't know how to find it. Please help me.

- `primeBaseSize` - The number of primes in the prime base
- `maxPrimeThreshold` - Is used to calculate the logs threshold
- `minPrimeSize` - Used to limit the sieving to start from primes higher than this value
- `loopsSize`, `loopsCount` - `loppSize` times `loopsCount` is equal to the sieving bound
- `longRoundingError` - A threshold for picking the max long value for the vector extraction phase

Answer (score 1):

Get a copy of [Prime Numbers - A Computational Perspective](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Prime-Numbers-Computational-Carl-Pomerance/dp/0387252827) by Crandall and Pomerance. See [here](https://www.iacr.org/books/2014_sp_crandall_numbertheory.pdf) for a review. It is rather old (2005), but then so is the Quadratic Sieve. It has an extensive discussion of the algorithm, by its inventor Carl Pomerance, and tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: This is not the kind of answer I was looking for. I am looking for an optimization strategy

Comment: @IlyaGazman: Yes, and that would take me five pages to explain. So check out that book! This is all well-known stuff.

Comment: I got a good familiarity with Quadratic Sieve. My current implementation is only 5 times slower than msieve. What I am asking is not how to find the optimal B bound and sieving bound in the classical implementation, but rather how to to approach finding an optimal configuration for my own quite unique, implemintation.

Comment: @IlyaGazman: But then surely that is your problem? I really don't know how you expect us to help you.

Comment: I want to know if there is a mathematical way to **search** for a good approximation for algorithm configurations. Surely there must be some generic approach for it.

Comment: @IlyaGazman: No, I don't think there is, unless you have access to Google's AI department. You must experiment and adjust.

Comment: Yes exactly. Unfortunately I am not friends with Google AI. But experiment and adjust is what I have been doing so far. I am looking for a smarter way to experiment. It can't be that everyone needs to reinvent the wheel when it comes to it